# How to show the price values with decimal cases?

Tags: php, laravel

Im showing the price and subtotal in the view like below.

Do you know how to show the currency values with decimal like 10.00 instead of just 10?

```
 @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
    <li>
        <span>{{$k}}</span> <!-- center bench -->
        <span>{{$selectedType['quantity']}}</span> <!-- example: 2 -->
        <span>{{$selectedType['price']}}</span>   <!-- example: 10 -->
        <span>{{$selectedType['subtotal']}}</span>  <!-- example: 20 -->
    </li>
@endforeach
<li>
    <span>TOTAL</span>
    <span>{{$selectedType['total']}}</span> 
</li>
```

In the TicketType model I have this method but Im not having success using it for the above context. But also dont know if is the best solution.

```
 public function showPrice(){
        return money_format('%i€', $this->price);
    }
```

Comment: Anything useful here? http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#114074

Comment: What do you mean you're not having any success using it? Why don't you do `$selectedType->showPrice()` (assuming `$selectedType` is TicketType)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHPs [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) method.

It looks like you're using Euros, this allows you to set the decimal and thousands place separator.

```
// blade.php
{{ number_format($this->price, 2, ',', '.') }}

// Model.php
public function showPrice() {
    return number_format($this->price, 2, ',', '.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `number_format()`?

```
public function showPrice() {
    return number_format($this->price, 2)
}
```